# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) when using deleteObject: on Core Data store

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, exc-bad-access

In my application, I'm removing (or trying to remove) all records from two core data stores before adding new ones in place. They are 2 simple stores, containing data related to records in the address book (VIContacts contains contact id and a vcard hash (integer), VIGroup contains group id and group name).

To remove all contacts from a store, I use this piece of code, in a method called `-clear:`:

```
NSArray *allOldRowsInVIContacts = [[mainContext fetchObjectsForEntityName:[VIContact name]
                                               includePropertyValues:NO
                                               withPredicate:nil] copy];

for (NSManagedObject *obj in allOldRowsInVIContacts) {
    @try {
        [mainContext deleteObject:obj];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception Triggered: %@", exception.reason);
        [NSException raise:exception.reason format:@"thrown on vicontacts."];
    }
}

[allOldRowsInVIContacts release];

if (![mainContext save:error]) {
    return NO;
}

NSArray *allOldRowsInVIGroups = [[mainContext fetchObjectsForEntityName:[VIGroup name]
                                                 includePropertyValues:NO
                                                         withPredicate:nil] copy];

NSLog(@"all rows in VIGroups count: %d", [allOldRowsInVIGroups count]);

for (NSManagedObject *obj in allOldRowsInVIGroups) {
    @try {
        [mainContext deleteObject:obj];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception Triggered: %@", exception.reason);
        [NSException raise:exception.reason format:@"thrown on vigroups."];
    }
}

[allOldRowsInVIGroups release];

NSLog(@"at the end of -clear: Going to save context.");

/* SAVE */
if (![mainContext save:error]) {
    return NO;
}
```

The app always seem to crash around the VIGroup region.

The crash log is as follows:

```
Crashed Thread:  5  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
...
Thread 5 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff82532574 __CFBasicHashRehash + 1412
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8252b41b __CFBasicHashAddValue + 75
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff82531f78 CFBasicHashAddValue + 3176
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff82547899 CFSetAddValue + 121
4   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff8520e3dc -[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:] + 220
5   com.andrei.AddressBookApp       0x000000010004da9a -[AddressBookFrameworkSyncHelper clear:] + 490
6   com.andrei.AddressBookApp       0x000000010004c8f9 +[AddressBookFrameworkSyncHelper saveSnapshot:] + 105
7   com.andrei.AddressBookApp       0x000000010002d417 -[SLSyncOperation main] + 2631
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b68dbb6 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 684
```

**Other Info**

I have used Instruments to look for zombies, but none show up. There are some leaks in the application, but none related to Core Data.

There is no relationship between VIGroup and VIContact. They are separate, stand-alone entities.

Weirdly enough, the code never seems to go into @catch, as the console doesn't pick up any `Exception triggered: ...` messages before it crashes.

The error is thrown every now and then. The app seems to be more stable on Lion, but it crashes frequently on Mountain Lion and Snow Leopard.

Thanks. Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Updated with some more code

**MOC Created:**

I create an 'NSOperation' ('SLSyncOperation') and add it to a 'NSOperationQueue'. That `SLSyncOperation` is added to an `NSOperationQueue`:

```
[backgroundQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

// has a custom initializer
currentOperation = [[SLSyncOperation alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator
                                                                   andDelegate:delegate
                                                               forceRemoteSync:forceSync];

[backgroundQueue addOperation:currentOperation];
```

This is the `main` method of the SLSyncOperation (inherits from NSOperation):

```
- (void)main {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    syncProgressTracker = [SLSyncProgressTracker sharedProgressTracker];
    syncProgressTracker.currentStatus = SLSyncStatusIdle;

    // ... some other setup and sending notifications ...

    /* Set up. */
    managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

    // persistentStoreCoordinator is passed from the app delegate
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];

    // ... continues with other logic (syncing to a server), and the end of the method is: ...

    /* Tear down. */
    [managedObjectContext release];
    managedObjectModel = nil;

    [pool drain];
}
```

**MOC being used:**

I'm using the MOC in a singleton class, which is called from methods called from within the `SLSyncOperation`. I assume that in this case everything is happening in the same thread...? I will add some test methods to check this out.

*MOC being initialized in singleton class:*

```
+ (AddressBookFrameworkSyncHelper *)sharedHelper {
    if (!_sharedAddressBookHelper) {
        _sharedAddressBookHelper = [[AddressBookFrameworkSyncHelper alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedAddressBookHelper;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {        
        mainContext = [(AddressBookAppAppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        addressBookRef = [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook];

        // disable undo manager - uses less memory
        [mainContext setUndoManager:nil];        
    }

    return self;
}
```

After this, I'm using the MOC (`mainContext`) for saving, passing it around to other methods that use it etc. e.g.

```
//saving
[sharedABF.mainContext save:error];

// passing it to a Core Data method
VIContact *contactToAdd = [VIContact newOrExistingContactWithID:contactID
                                                      inContext:sharedABF.mainContext
                                                          error:error];

// that method looks like this
+ (VIContact *)newOrExistingContactWithID:(NSString *)contactID inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context error:(NSError **)error {    
    VIContact *theContact = [[context fetchObjectsForEntityName:[VIContact name]
                                          includePropertyValues:YES
                                                  withPredicate:
                              @"personID == %@", contactID] lastObject];

    if (theContact) {
        return [theContact retain];
    } else {
        // no contact found with that ID, return a new one
        VIContact *newContact = [[VIContact alloc] initAndInsertInContext:context];
        newContact.personID = contactID;
        return newContact;
    }
}

// and then fetch all rows in a Core Data entity and remove them
NSArray *allOldRowsInVIContacts = [mainContext fetchObjectsForEntityName:[VIContact name]
                                                   includePropertyValues:NO
                                                           withPredicate:nil];

for (NSManagedObject *obj in allOldRowsInVIContacts) {
    [mainContext deleteObject:obj];
}

if (![mainContext save:error]) {
    return NO;
}
```

The `fetchObjectsForEntityName` method is taken from [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/core-data-one-line-fetch.html).

I will try to see if the method is accessed from different threads with those methods you were mentioning. Hope this helps and gives you more info about how I'm using the MOC.

### More Information

I've named the thread where the mainContext is created as `SLSyncOperationThread.Name set.`. Before the point where the app crashes, I put an NSLog which prints out the name of the thread. It prints out this thread's name every time. So it doesn't seem to be a multi-thread issue. Especially because the app crashes every now and then now every time it reaches that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you say that the entities do not share a relationship, but what relationships do they have?

Second, you are getting a segmentation fault because a NULL pointer is being dereferenced.

Third, how many NSManagedObjectContext objects do you have, and how are they being accessed?

It looks like your `clear` method is being called from within an `NSOperationQueue` but it is not running on the main thread.  You are not supposed to access a single MOC from multiple threads concurrently.

My initial bet (without further information) is that you are accessing the MOC from multiple threads, which is a very bad thing.

Also, it looks like you are using Matt Gallagher's one line fetch.  I think it returns a `NSSet`, not `NSArray`... not that it seems to matter in this case, but always good to make sure you are using the proper types.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, you did not show how you are calling your `clear` method.  I bet it is in the stuff you replaced with the comment:

```
// ... continues with other logic (syncing to a server), and the end of the method is: ...
```

In any event, I am convinced that my first bet was right, and you are using the `mainContext` MOC from a different thread.  Your SLSyncOperation is running in its own thread, and is using its own MOC (the one it creates).  However, within that operation, it appears to be calling `saveSnapshot` which calls `clear` which, in turn, is using `mainContext` and not the MOC that was created to be used in that `NSOperation`.

The `mainContext` is the MOC owned by the AppDelegate, and used for stuff in the main thread.  It is being called and used in this "other" thread as well.  See your stack trace for proof.  That's rule number 1 of Core Data and threads.  You must not allow multiple threads concurrent access to the same MOC.

So, you are spinning a separate thread to do some work, and creating a local MOC to do the work.  All well and good.  However, you are still, from that thread, calling a method that explicitly wants to use the `mainContext` (in this case `saveSnapshot` is being called directly from your operation's `main`.

Now, you have several options:

Pass the loacally generated MOC to those methods so they operate on the proper MOC.  Maybe you intend to be snapshotting that MOC instead?

If you really intend for these methods to operate on the `mainContext` MOC, then you need to make sure they execute in the main thread.  I don't like the `perform` selectors, and prefer direct GCD.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Now you can call the saveSnapshot and other stuff that must use
    // mainContext since stuff in this block will execute on the main thread.
});
```

If you are using a main MOC, and have any other threads, I strongly encourage you to **NOT** use confinement concurrency for the main MOC.  Instead, I suggest this alternative:

```
managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
                        initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueCurrencyType];
```

Now, that MOC can be used just like the other one, with no code change (in other words, it will still act appropriately like a confinement MOC when used on the main thread).  However, it can more appropriately be used from other threads as well:

```
[managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    // Do anything with this MOC because its protected, and
    // running on the right thread.
}];
```

If necessary, you can call `performBlockAndWait` which is reentrant (dispatch_sync is **not** reentrant - it will cause a deadlock).  You still have to be careful with any `sync` operation to avoid a `deadly embrace` but `performBlockAndWait` can be called recursively from the same thread without deadlocking.

Comment: **1.** There are no relationships in my model. **2.** NULL (not nil). Does that mean I might be setting a value to NULL and then releasing it? **3.** I have 1 NSManagedObjectContext created at the beginning of an NSOperation (SLSyncOperation), released at the end of said NSOperation. **4.** Because I'm only using the MOC within the SLSyncOperation, I don't think I'm calling it from multiple threads. I think there was a way to test from which thread I am calling, so I could put an NSLog right above calls to the context.

Comment: Why not just post the entire code the creates and uses the MOC.  Snippets are good, but only if they contain the full context for diagnosis.

Comment: Is your NSOperation concurrent (did you implement -start)? Is your NSManagedObjectContext created inside the operation, or passed in from elsewhere? Is your NSOperation following *all* of the KVO guidance in the documentation?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to get the OP to post the code of how it was created and initiated, but...   Anyway, it sure looks like accessing a MOC on multiple threads.  Probably didn't set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1, or some other thing causing multi-thread access to the MOC.

Comment: @JodyHagins, I've added more example code. I'll also look into the possibility of having the MOC accessed from 2 threads. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Andrei You marked this as being the answer but I can't tell what, precisely, the solution was. I have a similar crash log so was wondering what your issue ended up being. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try to simply delete the file instead of the objects:

```
- (void)emptyDatabase{
    NSError * error;
    // retrieve the store URL
    NSURL * storeURL = [[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] URLForPersistentStore:[[[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject]];
    // lock the current context
    [self.managedObjectContext lock];
    [self.managedObjectContext reset];//to drop pending changes
    //delete the store from the current managedObjectContext
    if ([[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:[[[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject] error:&error])
    {
        // remove the file containing the data
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];
        //recreate the store like in the  appDelegate method
        [[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];//recreates the persistent store
    }
    [self.managedObjectContext unlock];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For now, I've implemented this as a workaround. I'll post back here if an error still occurs after this. Also, would be interesting to find out *why* this error was triggered in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are sharing an NSManagedObjectContext between two threads. That is just a guess, but considering the crash is happening on Thread 5 it seems pretty likely that this is the issue. You can only use an NSManagedObjectContext on one thread. I am guessing that you are creating `mainContext` on the main thread and then for whatever reason your `clear` method is being called on a background thread.

Here are some possible solution:

1. Create a new NSManagedObjectContext for use in the background thread.
2. You could ensure that your `clear` method is being called on the main thread. Here is one way to ensure that this happens:

   ```
   -(void)clear:(id)object {
       if(![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
           [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(clear:) withObject:object waitUntilDone:NO];
           return;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
3. You could theoretically `lock` and then `unlock` your NSManagedObjectContext. This is the solution I would recommend the least.

Reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454473/multithreaded-use-of-core-data-nsoperationqueue-and-nsmanagedobjectcontext) might also help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added some debug code to figure out if I am indeed calling the MOC from a different thread. Given that I am creating the MOC from an NSOperation, I guess I should check that the name of the thread is the same as the one from NSOperation, not the main thread, right?

Comment: Ok, so I've put an NSLog that checks to see on which thread the code is before clearing the `mainContext`. I create the `mainContext` in the `NSOperation` and I name that thread **SLSyncOperationThread.Name set.**. Later when the code reaches the NSLog before `clear:`, the NSLog prints out: **=== clear: method called from thread with name: SLSyncOperationThread.Name set.**, and then the app crashes. So it's not called from a different thread. This is more clear because the crash happens *every now and again* not every time.

Comment: @Andrei According to your code, mainContext is not created in the NSOperation.  It is assigned in the init method directly from the MOC in the app delegate.  You create a different MOC in the NSOperation.  See the edit on my post.  I think I explained exactly that point.

Comment: @JodyHagins, ok. very good point. I just see it now. I'll change it to get it from the NSOperation and then come back and let you know what happens.

Comment: I agree that the best way to handle this situation would be to create a new NSManagedObjectContext for your NSOperation. Did that solve the issue for you?