# Core Data Multithreading

Tags: ios, iphone

is possible have two thread on core data where one update application's database and the other read from database? i don't find a solution. is there some tutorials?

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want two thread...while one thread update database, with the other thread i want read database. What is the best solution? Make two database? have two configuration of model? or other? thanks in advance

Comment: So you want the UI to change as the database is changing? Why do you need to be reading and writing to it simultaneously?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454473/multithreaded-use-of-core-data-nsoperationqueue-and-nsmanagedobjectcontext?rq=1

Comment: No, i want change UI only after all update. I can show a UIAlert after update e so change the UI

Comment: I need to read and write simultaneously to don't block UI(application) while update database

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and actually it is the best practice.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/