# NSOperation for Core Data operations

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

My application makes a lot of heavy conversions from some format to `NSManagedObject`, so best way to me is to use `NSOperation` (or `Operation` in Swift 3) to make conversions from raw data to `NSManagedObject` and after all operations are finished save that context.

I can't use separate context for each `Operation`, because I my converter generates relationships (and they can be accessed only from same context) and application may run up to 20 conversions, so it's not cool to create new context and save it after each conversion.

So I need do create separate `OperationQueue` and ensure that all operations inside it are performed from same thread as context, I don't know how to do it.

I have only one mind: start everything inside `Operation.main()` as `context.perform { }`, but I don't really think that it is good solution.

I've found [similar thread at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486900/nsoperationqueue-designated-thread), but answers are outdated and I see that accepted answer is not clearly right.

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16178742/294949

Comment: @danh, yes, but NSManagedContext doesn't have counter for pending operations as I know, how can I know that all operations are completed? Do you think it will be safe just to make a lot of `.perform { }` and fire `.perform { try context.save() }` on last one? So it will run that save at the last.

Comment: The operations queue has an `operationCount` property.  Will that suffice?  You could be notified when that goes to zero with KVO.

Comment: @danh, context is not operation queue, you proposed to use context as NSOperation (like it that was in answer you provided). Or I don't understand the approach, can you post any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I've found to use Core Data in `Operation` is to make child context with `privateQueueConcurrencyType` without any additional `.perform` blocks (that private operation is already created in needed thread). I'm open to any other suggestions.

I've used `operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` to ensure safety and absence of merging conflicts, but I may propose that approach will work with concurrent operations, but it will be useless in most cases because operations will wait each while other context is not merged.

Be carefull about using `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()` in the same thread as `parentContext`, in most cases that will cause deadlock.

#### Example code

```
class ExampleOperation: Operation {
    let parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    init(parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.parentContext = parentContext
        super.init()
    }

    override func main() {
        if self.isCancelled { return }

        let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = parentContext

        // use here `childContext` context directly
        // e.g.: let result = try childContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        try? childContext.save()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using your own operation queue is **not** the best approach. With Core Data you need to use the built in Core Data concurrency via `mainQueueConcurrencyType` or `privateQueueConcurrencyType`, and then using `perform` or `performAndWait`. Using a custom operation queue as you describe will not work properly.

This will use dispatch queues managed by Core Data. You can't get a count of the number of pending operations directly but you can add a bunch of blocks at once with a final block that does whatever needs to happen when the import process is complete. It's also a good idea to save during the import process instead of only at the end, to keep memory use from getting out of hand, unless you're only importing a small amount of data.